# demand a password to register on wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, passwords

i got a site on wordpress and i need to demand a password on the register,if the user dont have this password he can't registe,i thought using a js function when the onsubmit event is trigred but that dont seems to be the best way to to that.

```js
var chave='the_key';

function validaChave(){
    var chaveForm=document.getElementById('chave');
    if(chaveForm==chave){
        return true;
    }
    alert('Error message');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Based on your variable name and your logic, `chaveForm` will never equal `chave`. `getElementById` does not return a string, it returns a Element object.

Comment: PHP tag doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: I've had success with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-invitation-codes/ Just treat the password like an invitation code.

Comment: @Peter i chose your plugin,but the register form(wp default) dont show a password input,but when i looked on the sql the user got a pass. you know whats the default pass?

Comment: Hi Matheus, Please see my answer below. Please mark it as solved if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't implement this with JavaScript because users can see it. And as this is a WordPress site then you have to implement it with PHP.

How to do it?

You can [create custom registration](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-allow-user-registration-on-your-wordpress-site/) form, then add a field to the form to handle this. Then when you submit a form, the php script on server-side will compare the value with the one stored on the server and return a response based on that.The value of the chave can be stored as **constant** (fixed value) or you can go farther and [use DB and hashing](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php)

hope I got you right.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to point out that your key "the_key" is **not secure.** Anyone with a modern web browser can easily access client side scripts running on web-pages, and see your key. Aside from this, someone can submit the form regardless of your checking code just as easily. Never trust the client! Do this validation server-side, like in PHP.

With that in mind, you can access the value of an element, assuming it's an `<input>`, with `document.getElementById('chave').value`

Answer (score 0):

Inconjunction with the plugin I recommended, please use these functions/hooks to allow the user to also choose their own password, you can put these in your themes function.php:

```
// ALLOW USERS TO CHOOSE PASSWORD
function show_extra_register_fields(){
?>
    <br />
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password**<br/>
        <input id="password" class="input" type="password" tabindex="30" size="25" value="" name="password" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="repeat_password">Repeat password**<br/>
        <input id="repeat_password" class="input" type="password" tabindex="40" size="25" value="" name="repeat_password" />
        </label>
    </p>
<?php
}
add_action( 'register_form', 'show_extra_register_fields' );

// CHECK FORMS FOR ERROR
function check_extra_register_fields($login, $email, $errors) {
    if ( $_POST['password'] !== $_POST['repeat_password'] ) {
        $errors->add( 'passwords_not_matched', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Passwords must match" );
    }
    if ( strlen( $_POST['password'] ) < 6 ) {
        $errors->add( 'password_too_short', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Passwords must be at least six characters long" );
    }
}
add_action( 'register_post', 'check_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );

// STORE USER SELECTED PASSWORD TO DATABASE
function register_extra_fields( $user_id ){
    $userdata = array();
    $userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
    if ( $_POST['password'] !== '' ) {
        $userdata['user_pass'] = $_POST['password'];
    }
    $new_user_id = wp_update_user( $userdata );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'register_extra_fields', 100 );
```